# Django general and app templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to customize my Django project, I will have a dashboard app and a home site app (you can enter from this home site to the dashboard with a URL).
I want to save a template for the HTML and css so both apps can use them.

I followed [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial07/#customizing-your-project-s-templates) tutorial on django official site, but I think I missed a setup because. This is the error: `Not Found: /css/style.css`.

At this point, my django project is structured this way, I think that I will add another app (module) to serve the home page:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    dashboard/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
            0001_initial.py
        models.py
        static/
        templates/
            polls/
                index.html
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    templates/
        css/
            style.css
```

And my settings.py is like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mysite/templates/'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Looks like you should be calling `/css/style.css` without dashboard.

Comment: I'll edit the post

Comment: I meant the file where you're trying to include `style.css`, sorry. Wondering whether you're linking to it incorrectly, etc. Also, a bit more of the traceback would help give context.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the post. You want the complete traceback?

Comment: why do you save the statics in templates directory??? you could save in static directory.... then, when You're calling from a template you must be use `{% static 'rute/inside/staticdirectory/style.css' %}` (this is the `<link />` tag)

Comment: German, I want other apps to access this static files, not just the dashboard

Comment: Putting the file in one app's static folder doesn't limit its use to just that app - it's just a way of keeping things organized.

Comment: How can I load another apps static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. The problem isn't with the templates settings, the problem is with the `staticfiles_dir`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    'var/css/style.css'
]
```

It is important to remark that the templates should have `<link rel="stylesheet" href={% static 'css/style.css' %}>`

I also loaded HTML files that are general templates for various apps.